# Процесс инициализации CLR

Tags: .net, clr

Перед тем как начать выполнять код CLR создаёт три домена приложения: SystemDomain, SharedDomain и DefaultDomain. Последний из них - экземпляр класса AppDomain и единственный именованный домен.

На картинке ниже представлено содержимое каждого домена:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

- На сколько я понимаю SystemDomain предназначен для загрузки и выгрузки AppDomain'ов, хранит пул строк процесса и различную информацию о каждом домене.
- SharedDomain больше похож на AppDomain и содержит код не зависящих от домена сборок.
- AppDomain - наше приложение.

Собственно, вопрос: Что из себя представляет домен? Если это изолированные разделы, в которых выполняется код и хранятся различные данные, как они физически выглядят? Не может же CLR разбить память процесса как ей хочется - у процесса есть конкретная структура определяемая ОС. Так же не ясно какие сборки загружаются в SharedDomain. Я должен специально как то указать, что сборку нужно загрузить в SharedDomain или все/некоторые сборки по-умолчанию туда загружаются? Как происходит взаимодействие с кодом сборок в SharedDomain?

Comment: А почему CLR не может разбить память процесса как ей хочется?

Comment: Каким образом ?

Comment: Ну, есть кусок памяти. Назначм его системным доменом. Есть другой кусок памяти, назначим его общим доменом.

Comment: Ну вы имеете ввиду размещение объектов в памяти. Я же говорю о самовольном распоряжении памятью всего процесса - расположение кучи, стека, служебных структур данных (EPROCESS) и т.д. У процесса есть конкретная структура, которую определила ОС. Речь идёт о возможности изменения этой структуры. Что вот этот домен из себя представляет физически? В процессе от одного до нескольких потоков. Для каждого домена создаётся поток или как это работает? Ведь по идее при запуске сборки в отдельном домене её код изначально должен работать в основном потоке...

Comment: Или код из разных доменов поочерёдно там выполняется?

Comment: Поочерёдно. С точки зрения ОС, нет никаких доменов, всё разделение лишь внутри .NET.

Comment: Это то понятно, что разделение лишь внутри .NET. А как работает переключение выполнения кода с одного домена на другой? И если код из определённого домена создаёт новый поток, то в этом потоке уже будет выполняться исключительно код из этого домена? Непрерывно?

Comment: Потоки существуют кросс-доменно. Если вы из одного потока производите вызов в другой домен, то вызывающий домен ждёт. Каждый объект лежит в своём домене, и, следовательно, каждый метод выполняется в контексте своего домена. (Но есть всякие ухищрения наподобие MarshalByRefObject или как оно там.)

Comment: Кросс-доменно? Вне доменов в смысле?

Comment: Ну, код потока начинается выполняться в одном домене, уходит в другой домен и возвращается. Потоки не «принадлежат» какому-либо домену.

Comment: А SystemDomain определяет очерёдность выполнения кода из разных доменов?

Comment: Не, а как он может? Код в потоке делает вызов в другой AppDomain, кто ему помешает? Вызов отрабатывает синхронно в том же потоке.

Comment: Т.е. при компиляции уже добавляются команды которые это делают?

Comment: Что именно делают? Вызов в другой AppDomain? Ну да, вы ж можете написать [`otherDomain.DoCallBack(...)`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.appdomain.docallback?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_AppDomain_DoCallBack_System_CrossAppDomainDelegate_).

Comment: Я могу написать? Нет. Я не об этом говорю. Если у меня в основном потоке выполняется код из нескольких доменов всегда, если так устроена clr, я же никаких действий не делаю в своём коде для этого. Сначала выполниться код из SystemDomain, потом из моего AppDomain, потом снова очередь SystemDomain и т.д.

Comment: Я не имею ввиду возможность вызывать код из доугого домена. Я пытаюсь понять  как работает clr. Если я запущу 2 сборки в одном процессе, то код каждой сборки должен изначально выполняться в основном потоке. Значит в основном потоке сначала сколько то отработает код первой сборки, потом будет очередь второй сборки. Как это переключение работает - вот вопрос. Или я не так вас понял, и для каждого домена существует свой поток, т.е. код во всех существующих в процессе доменах выполняется одновременно?

Comment: Смотрите. У вас в основном потоке выполняется код. Никакой «очереди» для выполнения нет, если кто-то из одного домена вызывает функцию из другого домена, выполнение продолжается в другом домене. Если вы грузите две сборки в один процесс, и вызываете функцию одного из них, то она отрабатывает до конца, и только затем вы сможете в этом потоке запустить любую другую функцию. Никакого переключения просто нет. Считайте, что потоки вообще ничего не знают о доменах.

Comment: А вот оно как. Значит при создании нового домена AppDomain вызывается метод `CreateDomain` который передаёт управление коду из SystemDomain (он же занимается этими делами). Код отработает и вернёт управление вызывающему методу.

Comment: А для чего нужен SharedDomain. Что там лежит и можно ли намеренно загрузить сборку туда (без всяких уловок - предоставляется ли такая возможность специально)?

Comment: Настолько я помню, в SharedDomain помещаются общие сборки, которые нужны всем. Например, ту, где лежит `string`.

Comment: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/junfeng/2004/08/05/domain-neutral-assemblies/

Comment: А могу ли я сам загрузить сборку в SharedDomain?

Comment: Указать т.е. что эта сборка предназначена для загрузки в SharedDomain.

Comment: По идее, гарантированного способа нет. Вам понадобится [вот такой атрибут](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.loaderoptimization?view=netframework-4.7.2) на Main, и положить сборку в GAC, а также все её зависимости.

Comment: Я так понимаю, сборки в SharedDomain загружаются какие то строго конкретные: mscorlib (основные типы данных из System namespace) либо наш код, который мы пометили нужным атрибутом. Помимо этого shareddomain управляет картой сборок, применяемой в качестве поисковой таблицы при управлении совместно используемыми зависимостями между сборками в appdomains.

Comment: Так вот ещё вопрос: Весь IL код, принадлежащий нашей сборке, храниться в DefaultDomain? По мере вызова методов выполняется компиляция их тел. А если в методе ссылки на другие методы? Вместо них подставляется адрес функции компиляции с параметром ссылки на компилируемый блок, которая вернёт адрес откомпилированного кода?

Comment: _"Я так понимаю, сборки в SharedDomain загружаются какие то строго конкретные: mscorlib (основные типы данных из System namespace) либо наш код, который мы пометили нужным атрибутом."_ - Я тут почитал про [`LoaderOptimizationAttribute`](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/framework/app-domains/application-domains) и понял, что всё работает не так. Наш код размещается по прежнему в DefaultDomain, а вот код всех других сборок (либо только сборок со строгим именем) загружается в SharedDomain.

Comment: @VladD Всё же вот такой ещё вопрос: верно ли что весь IL код сборки расположен в домене и где хранятся адреса уже откомпилированных методов? А если сборка содержит машинный код (обработана с ngen)?

Comment: Смотрите, если у вас сборка попала в SharedDomain, то она лежит в GAC, и все сборки, на которые она ссылается — тоже. Поэтому компиляция всех функций происходит в SharedDomain, по идее.

Comment: Как я понимаю, у функции есть адрес, и при компиляции ссылок на функцию он и подставляется. Если функция ни разу не вызывалась, то по адресу функции лежит по сути заглушка: jump на код JIT-компиляции + IL-код самой функции. После JIT-компиляции этот jump + IL заменяется на нормальный скомпилированный код функции.

Comment: Т.е. происходит не прямой вызов внутренней недокументированной функции компиляции, а вызов заглушки, а потом уже вызов функции компиляции. У функции есть адрес - да, но он нигде не ставиться в соответствие этой функции (в машинном коде). Есть просто call и этот адрес. Значит при компиляции IL кода, содержащего вызов других методов, должен происходить какой то поиск, проверка того, не откомпилирована ли эта функция уже? Должно быть соответствие - имя функции и её адрес, чтобы потом его подставить вместе с call.

Comment: Выходит, на моменте компиляции создаётся эта заглушка, а при вызове происходит, соответственно, переход на неё и компиляция вызываемого метода. Это логично. Но ведь при дальнейшем использовании этого метода будет сделана ссылка не на эту "заглушку". Будет сделана ссылка на откомпилированный код, который где-то поставлен методу в соответствие. Где?

Comment: Скомпилированный код кладётся по тому же адресу, что и заглушка.

Comment: Никакого поиска не происходит. просто код функции такой «запустить JIT-компилятор с параметром = адрес функции». И выполнение этого заменяет код на откомпилированный код

Comment: _"Скомпилированный код кладётся по тому же адресу, что и заглушка"_ - Вот это всё поясняет. Спасибо

Comment: Подождите)) Но выходит аналогичная ситуация: нужно запомнить где лежит эта заглушка (ну после компиляции уже не заглушка, а откомпилированный код). У нас же в IL коде нет никаких адресов - есть только ссылка на такой то метод в таком классе. После того как будет загружена сборка, содержащая нужный метод, будет выделен отдельный блок памяти, в нём сформируется заглушка. При вызове заглушки произойдёт компиляция IL кода нужного метода, и тело заглушки будет заменено на этот откомпилированный код. Пусть этот откомпилированный код лежит где то в памяти процесса...

Comment: ... (кстати, я так понимаю он будет лежать вне самого домена, ведь домен содержит только IL код и служебные структуры?). Но в любом случае когда будет снова сделана ссылка на этот самый метод, придётся найти где тот откомпилированный код лежит.

Comment: Почему нет адресов? У функций есть обычные адреса функций, как в нормальных EXE. Настраиваются как обычно через relocation table. А как IL привязывает тип + имя функции к адресу — ну как обычно, через метаданные, как ещё? Наверняка в Рихтере есть.

Comment: Да. Через метаданные. Но метаданные содержат лишь сведения о функции в IL коде. Чтобы использовать функцию нужно её откомпилировать и запомнить адрес с откомпилированным кодом. Ладно бы он совпадал с адресом в метаданных (т.е. IL код метода заменялся на откомпилированный код прямо внутри домена, но это не так совсем происходит да и невозможно реализовать, ведь размер IL кода <> размер аналогичного машинного).

Comment: Вы наверное не так поняли что я хочу узнать. Поясню на примере. Вот есть у нас в методе Main вызов `Console.ReadLine` дважды. Первый раз - "прямой", второй - через другую функцию типа `void f() { Console.ReadLine(); }`. Когда наступит время запустить Main, будет выполнена его компиляция и в результате будет простым языком это: `call адрес_заглушки_r; call адрес_заглушки_f`. При всём этом будет создано две заглушки, содержащих вызов функции JIT компиляции с передаваемым в неё адресом компилируемого блока IL кода.

Comment: При вызове заглушки сработает внутренняя функция, которая, выходит, себя в памяти перепишет на откомпилированный код? Далее этот код будет выполнен. Первый вызов понятен. Переход на откомпилированный код в заглушка_r. Второй переход не понятен: заглушка_f содержит вызов `Console.ReadLine`. Что произойдёт при вызове? Переход на заглушка_r_2 с откомпилированным телом `Console.ReadLine` или переход на заглушка_r? Конечно второй вариант. Но надо запомнить что вызову `Console.ReadLine` идёт в соответствие адрес заглушка_r. Как это происходит?

Comment: @VladD Вам понятно моё пояснение к вопросу?

Comment: Понятно, но мне нужно посмотреть в Рихтере точный ответ :)

Comment: @VladD Вопрос возник при чтении Рихтера)

Comment: @VladD Нашли ответ в Рихтере?

Comment: Ну т.е. понимаете, что нужно где то сохранить адрес откомпилированного кода для его дальнейшего использования. Вроде и в [стандарте](https://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-335.pdf) такого нет...

Comment: @VladD https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/887250/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B3%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD-%D0%BA%D1%8D%D1%88-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0-jit-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B0