# Как организован кэш кода JIT компилятора?

Tags: clr, jit

Этапы JIT компиляции кода в среде CLR выглядят примерно так:

1. При компиляции кода, содержащего вызов определённого метода, для этого метода выделяется место в памяти называемое заглушкой. Заглушка содержит вызов внутренней недокументированной функции компиляции и указатель на блок IL кода метода.
2. Когда наступает момент вызова метода, происходит вызов функции компиляции, которая компилирует IL код в машинные команды, а так же перезаписывает содержимое заглушки на этот код.
3. Происходит выполнение метода.

Поскольку, как всем известно, CLR в целях оптимизации не выполняет компиляцию одного и того же метода каждый раз, нужно где-то хранить соответствия блоков откомпилированного кода и имена методов.

Рассмотрим для ясности вопроса такой пример:

Имеем такой код на C#:

```
void Main() {
    Console.ReadLine();
    ReadLine();
}

void ReadLine() {
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Под методы `Console.ReadLine` и `ReadLine` будут выделены, соответственно, Stub1 и Stub2. Как примерно будет выглядеть откомпилированный код:

```
call stub1
call stub2
```

При вызове stub1 выполнится компиляция метода `Console.ReadLine`, его код запишется в stub1 и после этого выполнится. Тут ничего вопросов не вызывает.

А вот при вызове stub2, произойдёт, конечно же компиляция `ReadLine`, что будет выглядеть так:

```
сall Console.ReadLine
```

И ответ на вопрос что будет вызвано: stub1 или новый stub3, содержащий аналогичный код - ответ очевиден. Но для того, чтобы вызвать stub1, таким образом не выполняя компиляцию `Console.ReadLine` заново, нужно запомнить адрес stub1 и поставить его в соответствие методу `Console.ReadLine`. Как это делается?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Изначально все обычные .NET методы, выполняют  `call` с адресом переходника. Сам переходник содержит вызов функции `PrecodeFixupThunk`, [вот ёё код](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/master/src/vm/amd64/unixasmhelpers.S#L10):

```
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
// PrecodeFixupThunk
//
// The call in fixup precode initally points to this function.
// The pupose of this function is to load the MethodDesc and forward the call the prestub.
//
// EXTERN_C VOID __stdcall PrecodeFixupThunk()
LEAF_ENTRY PrecodeFixupThunk, _TEXT

        pop     rax         // Pop the return address. It points right after the call instruction in the precode.

        // Inline computation done by FixupPrecode::GetMethodDesc()
        movzx   r10,byte ptr [rax+2]    // m_PrecodeChunkIndex
        movzx   r11,byte ptr [rax+1]    // m_MethodDescChunkIndex
        mov     rax,qword ptr [rax+r10*8+3]
        lea     METHODDESC_REGISTER,[rax+r11*8]

        // Tail call to prestub
        jmp C_FUNC(ThePreStub)

LEAF_END PrecodeFixupThunk, _TEXT
```

Как видно из кода, здесь передаются индексы переходника (`m_PrecodeChunkIndex`), и индекс структуры `MethodDesc` (`m_MethodDescChunkIndex`). Эти индексы вычисляются из адреса переходника. CLR специально для этого размещает их один за другим в памяти. Функция `ThePreStub` принимает на вход индекс переходника (что бы знать, где подменять код), и индекс структуры `MethodDesc`, что бы знать, куда записать указатель на скомпилированный метод.

В документации про [Method Descriptor](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/master/Documentation/botr/method-descriptor.md) написано:

> MethodDesc (method descriptor) is the internal representation of a
>   managed method. It serves several purposes:
>
> - Provides a unique method handle, usable throughout the runtime. For normal methods, the MethodDesc is a unique handle for a  triplet.
> - Caches frequently used information that is expensive to compute from metadata (e.g. whether the method is static).
> - Captures the runtime state of the method (e.g. whether the code has been generated for the method already).
>     Owns the entry point of the method.

`Method Descriptor` помнит, есть ли скомпилированная версия метода, и где ее адрес.

`ThePreSub` вызывает `PreStubWorker`, который вызывает метод `MethodDesc::MakeJitWorker`. Вот как выглядит документация перед [кодом этого метода](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/release/2.0.0/src/vm/prestub.cpp#L254):

```
// MakeJitWorker is the thread safe way to invoke the JIT compiler
// If multiple threads get in here for the same pMD, ALL of them
// MUST return the SAME value for pstub.
//
// This function creates a DeadlockAware list of methods being jitted
// which prevents us from trying to JIT the same method more that once.
```

Как видно, это метод достаточно умный, что даже если из нескольких потоков запросят компиляцию одного метода, JIT сделает ее один раз, а остальные потоки просто будут ждать.

До компиляции переходник выглядит так:

```
call        PrecodeFixupThunk
```

После компиляции на место `call` вставляется безусловный переход с адресом скомпилированого метода:

```
jmp         000007FE92A60500
```

На хабре есть очень детальная статья, описывающая как все устроено: https://habr.com/post/307088/

Comment: В CLR существует 4 precode-переходника. Чем среда руководствуется при выборе одного из них?

Comment: Структуры MethodDesc складываются в массивы (chunks). Это делается для экономии места. Но каким образом эта экономия достигается? И по какому принципу эти MethodDesc складываются в один MethodDescChunk? По принадлежности к одному классу?

Comment: Создаётся ли это всё дело динамически или существует ещё до начала выполнения точки входа? В любом случае вызов всех методов не предугадать заранее (да и это накладно как то)... Т.е. должен быть найден MethodDescChunk для нужного класса и в него добавлен MethodDesc для компилируемого метода?

Comment: Старшие биты MethodDesc содержат её индекс в MethodDescChunk, а младшие - индекс слота в MethodTable. На один MethodDescChunk приходится одна MethodTable. Сам слот содержит либо адрес откомпилированного кода либо адрес переходника в зависимости от статуса метода (откомпилирован/выделен). Может ли адрес находиться в MethodDesc непосредственно или он всегда содержится в слоте?

Comment: @D.Stark В статье написано назначение всех переходников. Экономия места достигается за счет того, что не хранятся адреса (которые занимают 4/8 байт на х86/х64), а вместо них хранится 2 индекса (размером 1 байт), и 1 адрес на 256 переходников. Это все создается в момент загрузки .NET dll. По поводу последнего вопроса я не знаю. Если много вопросов - лучше задайте отдельно их, комменты обычно для небольших уточнений.

Comment: Всё верно. При загрузке метода для каждого его класса создаётся MethodDescChunk содержащий MethodDesc для каждого метода. MethodDesc включает метку метаданных метода и индекс слота в MethodTable. Полагаю, MethodDescChunk владеет базовым адресом MethodTable, чтобы вычислять адреса слотов. Слот указывает на откопилированный метод или на заглушку в зависимости от статуса метода (откомпилирован/выделен).

Comment: Но вроде это всё равно один и тот же адрес в слоте, ведь заглушка перезаписывается машинным кодом, а адрес её начала не меняется.

Comment: MethodTable существует для каждого класса отдельно. MethodDescChunk просто содержит 256 записей. А вот как MethodDesc тогда укажет индекс слота? Индексы же не абсолютные, а относительные... Нужно где то базовый адрес MethodTable взять. Значит, он не в MethodDescChunk хранится.

Comment: @D.Stark таких деталей я не знаю